# How to transform preg_replace to wrap words from an array, instead just one word?

Tags: php

I have the following method, which checks for the word 'example' in a text, and if it finds is, it wraps a `span` around it:

```
function highlightWords($dreams) {
    $wrap_before = '<span class="highlight_match">';
    $wrap_after  = '</span>';
    $key_words = 'example';

    $dreams = json_decode($dreams);

    foreach ($dreams as &$value) {
        $value->dream = preg_replace("/($key_words)/i",
            "$wrap_before$1$wrap_after", $value->dream);
    }
    return $dreams;
}
```

I've tried to modify the `$key_words` variable to an array, so I could give multiple words as parameter, but it always gives back an error. Can I even do this with this approach?

Comment: implode your keywords array; e.g: `$key_words = implode('|', $key_words);` - this will give you a string like `foo|bar|baz`

Comment: @DarraghEnright thanks!

Comment: No problem :) I'll submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert your array of keywords into a string that you can use as your regex.

It appears that you want to do a whole word match on one of a number of keywords, so use the [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (the `|` character) as a delimiter.

For example, given an array of:

```
$key_words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
$key_words = implode('|', $key_words);
```

Yields the following string:

> foo|bar|baz

Which you can then use in place to create your regex of key words:

```
// /(foo|bar|baz)/i
preg_replace("/($key_words)/i", 
    "$wrap_before$1$wrap_after", $value->dream);
```

Hope this helps :)